# Is there a value missing to correctly align my output?

Tags: java

I am getting the correct information in my output but would like for it to look more organized in terms of the numbers being in a straight column.

```
public class Main 
    {
      public static double classAvg(int [] list) 
      {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x:list)
          sum+=x;
        return (double)sum/list.length;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) 
          throws IOException 
      {
          Scanner f = new Scanner(new File("students.in"));
          int N = f.nextInt();

          String [] name = new String[N];
          int [] avg = new int[N];
          for (int x=0;x<N;x++)
          {
            f.nextLine();
            name[x]=f.nextLine();
            avg[x]=f.nextInt();
          }
          for (int x=0;x<N;x++)
              out.printf("%s\t%d\n",
                  name[x],avg[x]);
          out.printf("Class average = %.1f\n",
              classAvg(avg));
      }
    }
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Tom Jones   100
Sally Field 95
Travis Farmer   75
Joe Dirt    70
Carmen SanDiego 98
Class average = 87.6
```

Comment: change `%s` to `%40s`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with printf format e.g. `%-20s` which is a left justify with the width of 20 chars.

```
out.printf("%-20s\t%d\n", name[x],avg[x]);
```

Please refer the javadoc or examples like this from [DZONE](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples)
Other librarys / classes e.g. StrBuilder from apache commons lang have also nice functions for formatting.